# Exercise in conditional probability

Tags: probability

> Suppose there are three fair dice, one blue and two red. All three dice are rolled, independent of one another. If a die rolls even, then it is kept for the next roll. Otherwise, if it rolls odd, it is discarded and never rolled again. This process continues until there are no dice remaining.
>
> Given that the blue die was the only one remaining at some point, then find the probability that it took exactly $3$ rolls before there were no dice left.

I think I was able to do this by explicitly writing the scenarios in which the above can occur. In the following, the letters correspond to the colored die remaining.

Scenario 1: (R,R,B) $\xrightarrow{1st \; toss}$ B $\xrightarrow{2nd \; toss}$ B $\xrightarrow{3rd \; toss}$ none

Scenario 2: (R,R,B) $\xrightarrow{1st \; toss}$ (R,B) $\xrightarrow{2nd \; toss}$ B $\xrightarrow{3rd \; toss}$ none

Scenario 3: (R,R,B) $\xrightarrow{1st \; toss}$ (R,R,B) $\xrightarrow{2nd \; toss}$ B $\xrightarrow{3rd \; toss}$ none

Due to independence and the fair die assumption, scenario $1$ occurs with probability, $\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{32}$. Similarly, scenario $2$ occurs with probability, $2\frac{1}{64} = \frac{1}{32}$ (since there are $2$ red die). Finally, the last scenario occurs with probability, $\frac{1}{128}$. Adding the three probabilities gives, $\frac{9}{128}$.

Does this answer seem reasonable? Since this is a conditional probability, I'm assuming Bayes' theorem was meant to be used here, but I'm not sure to approach it that way.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think your answer is right. Aren't you assuming that there are exactly $3$ rolls, and then finding the probability that $B$ is the only die left at some point? The question is the other way round. My attempt: The probability that a particular die lasts for exactly $n$ rolls is $2^{-n}$. Hence the probability that it lasts for strictly less than $n$ rolls is $2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + \cdots + 2^{1-n} = 1 - 2^{1-n}$. Now if $B$ was the only die left at some point, then there is $n$ such that B lasted for exactly $n$ rolls while $R_1$ and $R_2$ each lasted for less than $n$ rolls. The probability of this for a given $n$ is $2^{-n}(1 - 2^{1-n})^2$. The overall probability that it happens is the sum over all $n \ge 1$, which works out to $5/21$. The probability that it happens for $n = 3$ is $9/128$. So the answer is $9/128$ divided by $5/21$, that is $189/640$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So my computation was the probability that gold was the only one remaining at some point **and** the game lasted exactly $3$ trials? The numerator of the actual conditional probability?

Comment: Yes, that's it.